# Android - button on click scroll to top of view

Tags: android

I want to place a button at the bottom of my view (under the ExpandableListView) and the when the button is clicked, it should scroll to the top of the view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try putting the following line in the onClick for that bottom button

```
yourScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make button static at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Found the solution. Adding android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to the RelativeLayout around Button did the trick.
'<RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView>
</ScrollView
<RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>'