# Android facebook like scroll to the top

Tags: android, facebook, listview, scroll

I want to implement scroll to the top on my listview in the way facebook(see picture: new stories) / 9gag apps have it done. So that when you start scrolling up it shows.
Since I found both in 9gag and facebook up the same functionality I am guessing there is either a integrated android functionality or a library that already does this but I cannot find anything about it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: new stories]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889793/android-listview-scrolling-to-top

Answer (score 0):

If you want an immediate scroll to the top, try [scrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo(int,%20int)):

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

For an animated scroll, try [smoothScrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo(int,%20int)):

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use this for that scroll to top button, it will most probably solve your issue

```
yourScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940642/android-button-on-click-scroll-to-top-of-view)

Comment: Yeah I know how to scroll to the top but I want to make that smooth button that shows up when scrolling up and since I found 2 different apps with exactly the same button and functionality I believe there is a library or some existing code for it so I don't have to write my own

Comment: Well then u can head over [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) and i think u can use one of those methods, its just a simple button i don't think u need to use a library for that, its just my openion anyway :)