# How to return to the top of an activity after scrolling using a button?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, button

I am creating an application that uses scroll view, and can not figure out how to implement a button that when pressed would take me from the bottom of a page after scrolling, to the top of the page. 
![bottom of the page]https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyWzQ.jpg 
![top of the page after button press]https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nLdq.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - button on click scroll to top of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940642/android-button-on-click-scroll-to-top-of-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's done like this considering that your ScrollView is `SV` and your button is `BTN` :

```
BTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       SV.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following line in the onClick for that bottom button

```
yourScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: How do I get it to work on the scroll view variable I want? Because it doesnt seem like i can use findviewbyid like i can on an imageview or button